# how many stars would be displayed by the following algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o, trace

Given the code below, how many stars (**on average**) would be displayed by the following algorithm? By tracing the first few iterations, I determined it would be 99, but other people tell me it should be 100. Why should it be 100, rather than a 99, though? When nNum is equal to numbers ranging from 1 to 9, we do have about 10 stars printed out for each corresponding random number generated (9 stars from the random numbers from 1 to 9, and 1 more star from the 0 that was generated as a random number for the previous nNum that resulted in nNum--). But when nNum = 10, we don't have that 1 extra star from a "previous" nNum that would generate a random number of 0. (I hope what I'm saying here makes sense...!)

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  int nNum = 10;
  printStar(nNum);
}

public static void printStar(int nNum)
{
  if(randNumGen.nextInt(10)<1)
    nNum--;
  if(nNum>0)
  {
    System.out.print('*');
    printStar(nNum);
  }
}
```

Comment: if `nNum` is decreased depending on the result of a PRNG, then the program could print 0 stars or it could print 1000. What kind of question is this?

Comment: What is randNumGen exactly?

Comment: @Villat Probably an instance of `Java.util.Random`

Comment: @NullUserException _Technically_ he does not show the `Random` declaration, so he could be using the same seed every time and we do not know, which would give the same amount every time.  Though this is probably not happening and he is just confused.

Comment: @NullUserException—I guess the question is asking for the # of stars to be printed *on average*... I'll update the question as well.

Comment: You're right, it's 99. You can prove that with a [Monte Carlo simulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method): instead of printing stars, have the code count the number of stars that would be printed. And then call the function a million times, keeping track of the average. The average is indeed 99, the median is about 96, the peak of the distribution is about 89, and outcomes with a probability above 1% range from about 69 to 114. Which means you're right, but your friends will claim they were close enough (which is true).

Comment: @user3386109—when nNum is doubled, though, then it would print 199. Then the problem is, my teacher told us this should be an O(n) function, which wouldn't exactly be right. I guess we can just approximate things here, then?

Comment: Yes, big-O is always just a rough approximation. When you say that something is O(n), it simply means that the exact answer is always less than `k*n` for some arbitrary value of `k` (and `n` greater than some arbitrary lower limit). So in this case, we could choose `k=10` and the lower limit on `n` as 10. Then, as long as the exact average is always less than `10*n` when `n>=10`, we can assert that the average is O(n).

Answer (score 1):

You're decreasing the variable value based on a Random number

```
if(randNumGen.nextInt(10)<1)
    nNum--;
```

Based on that, you will print at least 9 stars (assuming that the random generates always a 0). And, on the other hand, you could have infinite stars (although probabilistically speaking, it would not happen due to the PRNG seed)